# Android animate view does not resize other view

Tags: android, view, android-animation, android-transitions, objectanimator

I have an issue on Android and can't understand why. I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background_primary">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewContainer"
                android:layout_below="@+id/UpdatesBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
                    android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
                    android:overScrollMode="never" />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <Droid.UIElements.UIBanner
                android:id="@+id/UpdatesBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UIBanner is a custom view that content 2 buttons. One of them is binded on a Hide function which will animate the view.

```
 public void Hide()
    {
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "TranslationY", TranslationY, TranslationY - Height);
        animation.Start();
    }
```

This works but the view under the banner keep the same size and does not expand. If i only make a visibility gone on the banner then it works but no animation performed.

Following the states before and after animation:

[image: Before animation]

[image: After animation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is ValueAinmator

```
ValueAnimator viewAnim = ValueAnimator.OfInt(view.MeasuredHeight, viewHeight);
viewAnim.AddUpdateListener(new UpdateListener(view));
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.AnimationEnd += (sender, e) => EndAnim();
set.Play(viewAnim);
set.Start();
```

And the listener

```
class UpdateListener : Java.Lang.Object, IAnimatorUpdateListener
{
     Android.Views.View view;

     public UpdateListener(Android.Views.View pView)
     {
         view = pView;
     }

     public void OnAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
     {
         int value = (int)animation.AnimatedValue;
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.LayoutParameters;
         layoutParams.Height = value;
         view.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, don't know if it is the best way to achieve this bu well i have to animate the second view too. Following the code:

```
ObjectAnimator bannerAnimation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(banner, "TranslationY", banner.TranslationY, banner.TranslationY - banner.Height);
ObjectAnimator viewAnimation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(recycler, "ScaleY", recycler.ScaleY, recycler.ScaleY - banner.Height);
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.PlayTogether(bannerAnimation, viewAnimation);
set.Start();
```